# Session handling - how to differentiate between users

Tags: php, session

I'm using php sessions in my web application. For a single user, I need to store a number of variables, such as username, a flag to denote whether the user is logged in, etc. I thought of assigning an array to the $_SESSION, as a variable with all the values. Is there a way to achieve this?

Charu

Comment: what have you tried so far? you can just use something like $_SESSION['user_data'] = array($username, $user_id);

Answer (score 1):

Basically session *is* used to store `user-specific` data (state) and an identity. To enable the session for your page, call the `session_start()` method before you write anything to the response buffer.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  ....
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others told, session is a way for storing user-specific information. But if you are bewildered how it achieves, this is the story:

when someone start their browser and sends a request to your website, your web server will find out that is a new session of browsing your website, so it assign a unique number as it's *session id* and sends you back this session id (it is usually done by cookies. That is, the web server include a 'SET-COOKIE' http response header field. see more about [cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).
Now your browser sends that previously gotten "session id" in every future request it sends to your web server.
So, your web server can now distinguishes your traffic from others traffic, and every $_SESSION[] variable that you create, will assign to corresponding session id.
I hope it was clear.
See [this](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Sessions-and-Cookies/) link also for more information about sessions and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

what have you tried so far? you can just use data from the database as a unique identifier for a user:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_data'] = array('username'=>$username, 'user_id'=>$user_id);
```